# Date sorting is not working in muidatatable

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-volhard-jntyu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

this is my codesand box code. on date column result is not showing correctly.

Comment: Provide more details that what exactly is not working and what is required bu you.

Comment: Hey @sakhiya-dhruv, I suggest you to make evident the part of code you need help on by creating a `code` block in the Question you are asking. StackOverflo has a great syntax highlight and markdown support to let your question more understandable.

Comment: @Muhammad please open my codesand box beacuse you have to watch live output for sorting in muidatatable.

Comment: @LionelT Same for you have to see real time outpur.

Comment: The comment before tries to give you a wide view of the tools provided by SO to let the Questions asked more understandable and probably with more possibilities to get more answers. Hope the answer below fits for your _use-case_.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the `sort` behaviour is that you are trying to sort `strings` of dates where the **year** is the last element.

In case you could edit your data directly, try putting the year, the month and so on. Something like:

```
const data = [
  ...,
  [
     "Mason Ray",
     "Computer Scientist",
     "San Francisco",
     39,
     142000,
     "2019-10-03"
  ]
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/datesorting-6srgp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is an example using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)library to parse your input data.

A detail of how is done:

```
const data = [...].map(info =>
  info.map((val, index) => {
    const date = new Date(val)
    return index === 5
      ? isValid(date)
        ? format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        : val
      : val
  })
)
```